# How to get windows phone 8 internal storage size and/or sd size

Tags: size, storage

I'd like to make an app that displays the % free disk space. 
I can get the IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication().AvailableFreeSpace, but not the amount of global space (storage size) to do the math.

Any help?

Thanks.